# iOS SplitView / Universal help needed xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I'm just starting to learn objective-C and iOS development and I've ran in to some trouble with trying to migrate a iPhone app to iPad.

I've been reading Head First iPhone & iPad Development 2nd Edition, but chapter 7 " migrating to iPad" is out of date as of xcode 4.2.
The app is a demonstration of how to use a splitview with a table view and detail view.
They have a MainWindow-iPad.xib auto create when changing the iOS Application Target from iPhone to Universal.  But this isn't happening for me in xcode 4.2.  I have created a splitview controller programmatically in AppDelegate.  Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        MasterViewController *firstVC = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.secondVC = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

       UINavigationController *firstVCnav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *secondVCnav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.secondVC];

       UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVCnav, secondVCnav, nil];

       self.window.rootViewController= splitVC;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }else {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

The left side of the splitview (the table view) is perform good, but I can't get the Right side (the detail side) to change when I select different rows on the left side.  Here is the code I have in the MasterViewController class.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        AppDelegate *splitVCdetails = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        [splitVCdetails.secondVC drinkChanged:[self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }else {
        if (!self.editing) {
            if (!self.detailViewController) {
                self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            }
            self.detailViewController.drink = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
        }else {
            AddDrinkViewController *editingDrinkVC = [[AddDrinkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            editingDrinkVC.drink = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            editingDrinkVC.drinkArray = self.drinks;

            UINavigationController *editingNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editingDrinkVC];

            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:editingNavCon animated:YES];
            [editingDrinkVC release];
            [editingNavCon release];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I have in the DetailViewController class

```
-(void)refreshView {
    //Set up our UI with the provided drink
    self.drinkTextLabel.text = [self.drink objectForKey:NAME_KEY];
    self.ingredientTextBox.text = [self.drink objectForKey:INGREDIENTS_KEY];
    self.directionTextBox.text = [self.drink objectForKey:DIRECTIONS_KEY];
}

-(void)drinkChanged:(NSDictionary *)newDrink {
    self.drink = newDrink;
    [self refreshView];
}
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading "Head First iPhone and iPad Development" too. With help from KevinM's code 
I have created a UISplitController programmatically without xib. Here is my solution.

Here is the code I have at the beginning of AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
@synthesize splitViewController = splitViewController_;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [splitViewController_ release];
    [_navigationController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.    
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

        masterViewController.splitViewDetailView = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    }
    else {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the code I have in the MasterViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.editing) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [self.splitViewDetailView drinkChanged:[self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else {
            self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            self.detailViewController.drink = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else {
        AddDrinkViewController *editingDrinkVC = [[AddDrinkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        editingDrinkVC.drink = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        editingDrinkVC.drinkArray = self.drinks;

        UINavigationController *editingNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editingDrinkVC];

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:editingNavCon animated:YES];
        [editingDrinkVC release];
        [editingNavCon release];
    }
}
```

And add code from book on page 345 (method refreshView) and page 346 (property splitViewDetailView)